# Why does text align property slows down text animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

This is my very first question on this site so any suggestion about how to redact future ones, will be gratefully accepted.

Right now I have a text that is displayed from left to right as in a marquee, with an animation that scrolls the words in 30 seconds.

My problem is that even though the animation does what I want, it behaves weirdly with the speed of the animation, when the text is not fully displayed on the marquee, it will go at a constant speed, but as soon as the end of the text is reached, then it will slow down the animation in a very noticeable way.

This is the code I have right now:

HTML:

```
<div>  
  <p id="text" class="marquee smart-stops-small">{A-B}</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="text" class="marquee smart-stops-small">{A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-etc.}</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.smart-stops-small{
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.8em;
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 3.8em; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 15em }
    100% { text-indent: -55em }
}
```

I have created a Fiddle with the HTML and CSS that I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/zkv1t4g6/1/

### EDIT:

After touching a little bit the CSS class of **smart-stops-small** I've found out that the thing that breaks the animation is the *text-align* property

This updated fiddle shows it:
https://jsfiddle.net/zkv1t4g6/2/

### EDIT 2:

In the last fiddle I deleted most of the properties of the class, in this one the only one that's deleted is the `text-align: center;` and it seems that the animation works just fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/zkv1t4g6/3/

Now, the question changes, I want to know why the text align interferes with the speed of the animation. What is the interaction between those two?

Thanks!

Comment: This is happening because you're assigning `text-align: center;` to your text.

Comment: Thanks Hunter, that's what I've found out, now, is there any explanation for that?

Comment: @HunterTurner would you mind to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're assigning `text-align: center;` to your `<div>` that is being animated. Remove this line and the animation will flow smoothly.

**CSS**

```
.smart-stops-small{
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: center; /* <-- Remove */
  line-height: 3.8em;
  ...
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zkv1t4g6/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

right now don't have much time for the actual rationale behind it,
but I cant tell you what causes it:
`-webkit-box-orient: vertical;`

```css
.smart-stops-small{
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3.8em;
  display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 3.8em; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  /*-webkit-box-orient: vertical;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* Make it a marquee */
.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { text-indent: 15em }
    100% { text-indent: -55em }
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <p id="text" class="marquee smart-stops-small">{A-B}</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="text" class="marquee smart-stops-small">{A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-etc.}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I leave that as it is, there's no problem, the thing comes when I add the "text-align: center;" property to the smart-stops-small class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a very smooth transition, you should look to the `transform` property. Here's an example of your marquee using transform: https://jsfiddle.net/8o335a6r/

(I've added a grey background to the marquee contents so you can see how the marquee is moving).

The main change:

```css
.smart-stops-small{
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: center;
  background: #CCC;
}


.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.marquee__scroll {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee__scroll">
    <p class="marquee__content  smart-stops-small">A B C D E F G H I J K L M etc</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Why use `transform`?**

Using the CSS3 `translate` value means that your animation will utilise subpixel anti-aliasing, which means that instead of moving the item one pixel at a time, the browser can move elements in many more steps, making for a smoother transition.

Translations (using `translate`) are also performed in their own *layer* in the browser window which means the browser doesn't need to repaint the screen so often, leading to greatly improved rendering performance, particularly on mobile devices.

Comment: Tried this but the problem I face now is that the animation runs smoothly but it does not display the whole text.

Comment: Try adding a width value to `.smart-stops-small {}`, such as `width: 2000px;` and it will show all of the text within that frame.